# First time running pyspark - python starts, loads some libraries but not all, stops with error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Downloaded package spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7. Running it on Windows10.
Executed pyspark.cmd, python loads and things look ok until it calls shell.py. It loads the first few libraries fine (import atexit, os, platform, py4j) but throws an error and stops when importing pyspark. As far as I can tell all directories are in the required paths and other env variables are set properly, but I could be wrong. 
Attaching screenshot. I included sys.path. (sorry ignore the errors while displaying the path - newbie mistakes).[enter image description here][1]

Any help to get past this error and start working in pyspark would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 30, in <module>
import pyspark
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
File "C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
File "C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 36, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
File "C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 31, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
File "C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 18, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\pydoc.py", line 62, in <module>
import pkgutil
File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\pkgutil.py", line 22, in <module>
ModuleInfo = namedtuple('ModuleInfo', 'module_finder name ispkg')
File "C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 393, in namedtuple
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'
```

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Latest - 3.6 (32 bit). Looks like its tripping over this line in serializers.py - def namedtuple(*args, **kwargs):
        **bold** cls = _old_namedtuple(*args, **kwargs)  **bold**
        return _hack_namedtuple(cls)

Comment: Python 3.6 is not supported in spark 2.1.0, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41859224/7098262

Comment: Ok Thanks, will try that out first thing tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Thanks!