# How do I load text file to pySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, file-upload, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I want to load a file to PySpark local. But I can't and this error appears. Do you know, what I do?

[error spark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3iKs.jpg)

Comment: that seems to be environment issue, python and pyspark are incompatible. Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840296/pyspark-in-ipython-notebook-raises-py4jjavaerror-when-using-count-and-first

Comment: my python version is 3.7.6  and pyspark is '2.4.5' which is compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load a file via Spark, it also expects the protocol and by default, it expected either HDFS (distributed computing file system).

Since you are trying to do local file, follow this approach

```
sc.textFile("file:///path to the file/")
```

already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299923/how-to-load-local-file-in-sc-textfile-instead-of-hdfs)

Comment: Thanks ,  you mean for example this: 
        con = sc.textFile("file:///e:/friendship-data.txt")?
 I did, but that error apears yet!

Comment: I just tried in my mac machine and it worked.. not sure what going wrong in your windows box...... 20/04/11 14:25:30 WARN SparkContext: Killing executors is not supported by current scheduler.
>>> sc.textFile("file:////Users/test/dc2.txt")
file:////Users/hireshroy/dc2.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0