# Doing transformations in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have installed PySpark in my VS Code. I can create RDDs, but I can't perform transformations (like filter()) and when I try to execute it, a Py4JJavaError message appears.

I expected that my code runs without any issue

Comment: try some suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840296/pyspark-in-ipython-notebook-raises-py4jjavaerror-when-using-count-and-first)

Comment: Can you post the full Py4JJavaError you're getting and share the full code you're trying to execute as well